# JQuery On Change Event Functions

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

I have the following form fields. Whenever a user changes any of the address fields I want to update the longaddress field which is a concatenated string of all the form fields. I require some sanitization on the city and state field because the longaddress is passed into google maps autocomplete

```
<input id="address1" type="text" value="" name="address1" >
<input id="address2" type="text" value="" name="address2" >
<input id="city" type="text" value="" name="city" >
<input id="state" type="text" value="" name="state" >
<input id="postcode" type="text" value="" name="postcode" >
<input id="country" type="text" value="" name="country" >

<input id="longaddress" type="text" value="" name="longaddress" >
```

Currently I bind the fields to achieve the above using backbone as follows:

```
    initialize: function() {
        c.bindAll(this, "updateLongAddress"), this.on({
            "change:address1 change:address2 change:postcode change:country": this.updateLongAddress,
            "change:city": this.removeUnwantedContentFromProperty.bind(this, "city"),
            "change:state": this.removeUnwantedContentFromProperty.bind(this, "state")
        })
    },
    removeUnwantedContentFromString: function(a) {
        return a ? a.replace(/[\s,.]+$/, "") : void 0
    },
    removeUnwantedContentFromProperty: function(a) {
        var b = this.get(a),
            c = this.removeUnwantedContentFromString(b);
        if (b) return c !== b ? void this.set(a, c) : void this.updateLongAddress()
    },
    updateLongAddress: function() {
        this.set("longaddress", this.getComputedLongAddress().substring(0, 255))
    },
    getComputedLongAddress: function() {
        return this.get("address1") || this.get("address2") || this.get("city") || this.get("state") || this.get("postalcode") || this.get("country") ? c.reduce([this.get("address1"), this.get("address2"), this.get("city"), this.get("state"), this.get("postcode"), this.get("country")], function(a, b) {
            return b = b.trim(), b && (a = a ? a + ", " + b : b), a
        }, "") : ""
    }
```

I need to convert the above code to Jquery which I've attempted below but I'm struggling with the correct syntax to translate all the backbone functions into Jquery.

```
$(function () {

     initialize();

});


var initialize = function () {

    $("#address1, #address2, #postcode, #country").on('change', updateLongAddress);
    $("#city").on('change', removeUnwantedContentFromProperty);
    $("#state").on('change', removeUnwantedContentFromProperty);

};

var removeUnwantedContentFromProperty = function(a) {
     var b = this.get(a),
         c = this.removeUnwantedContentFromString(b);
     if (b) return c !== b ? void this.set(a, c) : void this.updateLongAddress()
};

var removeUnwantedContentFromString = function(a) {
     return a ? a.replace(/[\s,.]+$/, "") : void 0
};

var updateLongAddress = function() {
     this.set("longaddress", this.getComputedLongAddress().substring(0, 255))
};

var getComputedLongAddress = function() {
    return this.get("#address1") || this.get("#address2") || this.get("#city") || this.get("#state") || this.get("postcode") || this.get("country") ? c.reduce([this.get("address1"), this.get("address2"), this.get("city"), this.get("state"), this.get("postcode"), this.get("country")], function(a, b) {
         return b = b.trim(), b && (a = a ? a + ", " + b : b), a
        }, "") : ""
};
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you removing Backbone from your application or are you continuing to use its Models?

Comment: Are you trying to reverse-engineer minified code?

Comment: @76484 I'm removing Backbone and need to use pure Jquery code so yeah you could say it's reverse engineering.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend starting with a simple object to hold the state of the form values. This is similar in purpose to what the Model would be doing in your Backbone example:

```
var model = {
    address1: '',
    address2: '',
    city: '',
    state: '',
    postcode: '',
    country: ''
};
```

Note that the property names of the model map to the id attributes of our input fields. This will help us when mapping values.

The long address value is obtained by filtering-out the model values that are empty and then joining the remaining values with a comma delimiter. The result can be no greater than 255 characters in length:

```
var updateLongAddress = function () {
    var value = [
        'address1',
        'address2',
        'city',
        'state',
        'postcode',
        'country'
    ]
        .map(key => (model[key] || '').trim())
        .filter(val => Boolean(val.length))
        .join(', ')
        .substring(0, 255);

    $('#longaddress').val(value);
};
```

I will use a single event handler for all change events on our input fields. I will apply the character removal logic conditionally when the id of the changed element is "city" or "state". Otherwise, we simply set the value of the changed input to the corresponding model property and, if the value has changed, make the call to `updateLongAddress`.

```
$('#address1, #address2, #city, #state, #postcode, #country')
    .on('change', function (e) {
        var $target = $(e.target);
        var key = $target.attr('id');
        var value = $target.val();

        // string replacement logic from `removeUnwantedContentFromProperty`
        if (key === 'city' || key === 'state') {
            value = value.replace(/[\s,.]+$/, '');
        }

        // conditional update logic from `removeUnwantedContentFromProperty`
        // although this isn't applied to all fields in the example,
        // it shouldn't change anything to apply it to all inputs.
        if (model[key] !== value) {
            model[key] = value;
            updateLongAddress();
        }
    });
```